# "Quick test" en français et "vérification"

Tags: traduction, anglais, synonymes, mathématiques

> Remplaçant les données nous trouvons les coefficients demandés. *Une vérification rapide devrait vérifier les résultats*.

La phrase en italique se lit originalement en anglais :

> *A quick check would verify the results.*

Comment peut-on éviter la répétition d'un mot de la même famille, à savoir, vérification/vérifier dans la version française ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'utiliserai « [contrôle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/controle) ».

> Un contrôle rapide devrait vérifier les résultats.

Ou bien

> - Une vérification rapide devrait valider les résultats.
> - Une vérification rapide devrait confirmer les résultats.

Comment: On pourrait également dire "Une vérification rapide devrait confirmer les résultats".

Comment: @RémiHenry: Tout à fait, c'est ajouté.